# PHP Unserialize custom format & compare

Tags: php, compare

I'd like to convert the following string to array

```
{"0":"7","1":"12","2":"14","3":"13"}
```

I tried str_replace'ing but this isn't a proper sollution by far.
Further I checked if php's `unserialize()` could do it but that was no luck either.

What is the best way to convert

```
{"0":"7","1":"12","2":"14","3":"13"}
```

To

```
7,12,14,13
```

**Edit:**

The complete script should compare 2 of these strings to check if one of the numbers are the same.

So let's say String A is:

```
7,12,14,13
```

And String B is

```
4,9,11,12,15
```

It should set a var to '`true`' since `12` is found in both strings.
String A is formatted as above which needs to be unserialized

Thank you in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like JSON to me.

- Decode json with `json_decode`
- parse all elements to an integer with `intval`
- run `implode` on the array to convert it back to a string.

A quick one-liner would look like +/- this

```
implode(',', array_map("intval", json_decode('{"0":"7","1":"12","2":"14","3":"13"}', true)));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php

**Second problem**

To know if any value appears in both string `$A` and string `$B`, `array_intersect()` can be used.

```
$var = count(array_intersect(explode(',', $A), explode(',' $B))) > 0;
```

or if `$A` and `$B are arrays

```
$var = count(array_intersect($A, $B)) > 0;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode() function convert string to array.

```
$str={"0":"7","1":"12","2":"14","3":"13"}
$arr1=explode(",",$str);
$result=array();
foreach($arr1 as $substr)
{
    $syn=explode(":"$substr);
    $result[]=$syn[1];
}
print_r($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your string look like `JSON` string. You can parse `JSON` string using `json_decode` in PHP. Then used `implode` function for get comma separated values.

```
$str = '{"0":"7","1":"12","2":"14","3":"13"}';
$final_str = implode(",",json_decode($str,true));

echo $final_str;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `json_decode, explode, implode` functions

```
$string = '{"0":"7","1":"12","2":"14","3":"13"}';

$result_array = explode(",", implode(',', array_map("intval", json_decode($string, true))));
print_r($result_array);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => 7 [1] => 12 [2] => 14 [3] => 13 )
```